# The code changes happening on cloud build(deployment) is not reflecting in repository

Tags: google-cloud-functions, continuous-deployment, google-cloud-build

I'm using Cloud Build to deploy automatically during code push(Bitbucket). I'm changing the versions on prebuild which has a script to increase the number on JSON file.

The changes are not reflected on the mirrored repository and also I could not able to push that code to the bitbucket repo. how can I push the code from google cloud to bitbucket? or is there any other way?

Comment: AFAIK, your bitbucket repo is the main repo, the Source repo only a copy. You can't reflect the copy repo to the main.

Comment: Is there any way to push the changes back to main from Google Cloud? @guillaumeblaquiere